Wireguard Server and Peer not reachable
I've been searching for this issue for a while, I really need your help to see where I made the mistake.
I installed Wireguard on a VPS Server.
This is my Server's config:
[Interface]
Address = 10.8.88.1/24
#Address = fdb2:50d2:58fe::1/64
SaveConfig = false
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = <Server-Private-Key>

PostUp = ufw route allow in on wg0 out on eth0
PostUp = iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostUp = ip6tables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PreDown = ufw route delete allow in on wg0 out on eth0
PreDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PreDown = ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
#X-Desktop
PublicKey = x97QepJTQaNXXXXXXXXXMdFsG97P4gxT8TbL34=
AllowedIPs = 10.8.88.2/32  
PersistentKeepalive = 25

[Peer]
#Hauwei Y9S Phone
PublicKey = N4liWuOjJFXXXXXXXXXXd/9JCnT5OGUxgYWw=
AllowedIPs = 10.8.88.3/32
PersistentKeepalive = 25

On My Machine (Peer) I have the following Config:
[Interface]
PrivateKey = QO+XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXtVsLZh1VXo=
Address = 10.8.88.2
#Address = fdb2:50d2:58fe::2/64

[Peer]
PublicKey = YyC+DXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXCUBvxMTzCw=  # Server Public Key
AllowedIPs = 10.8.88.0/24
Endpoint = 107.X.X.X:51820 # Server IP Address

I have allowed the port through UFW:
#ufw status
51820/udp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
Anywhere                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on wg0           
Anywhere (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6) on wg0      

Anywhere on wg0            ALLOW FWD   Anywhere on eth0          
Anywhere on eth0           ALLOW FWD   Anywhere on wg0           
Anywhere (v6) on wg0       ALLOW FWD   Anywhere (v6) on eth0     
Anywhere (v6) on eth0      ALLOW FWD   Anywhere (v6) on wg0

I even disabled UFW with no success!
I have checked ipv4 forwarding as well:
~# sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

if I do #ip a It shows that the interface is UP:
22: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none 
    inet 10.8.88.1/24 scope global wg0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

lsmod | grep wireguard
wireguard              90112  0
libchacha20poly1305    16384  1 wireguard
ip6_udp_tunnel         16384  1 wireguard
udp_tunnel             20480  1 wireguard
libblake2s             16384  1 wireguard
curve25519_x86_64      36864  1 wireguard
libcurve25519_generic    49152  2 curve25519_x86_64,wireguard

The status of the service shows that it is Active both on Server and my Machine(peer)
sudo systemctl status wg-quick@wg0
● wg-quick@wg0.service - WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/wg-quick@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Thu 2024-09-26 03:12:36 WIB; 18min ago
       Docs: man:wg-quick(8)
             man:wg(8)
             https://www.wireguard.com/
             https://www.wireguard.com/quickstart/
             https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg-quick.8
             https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg.8
    Process: 740891 ExecStart=/usr/bin/wg-quick up wg0 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 740891 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 301ms

Sep 26 03:12:36 racknerd-04bcdf wg-quick[740891]: [#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
Sep 26 03:12:36 racknerd-04bcdf wg-quick[740891]: [#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63
Sep 26 03:12:36 racknerd-04bcdf wg-quick[740891]: [#] ip -4 address add 10.8.88.1/24 dev wg0
Sep 26 03:12:36 racknerd-04bcdf wg-quick[740891]: [#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev wg0
Sep 26 03:12:36 racknerd-04bcdf wg-quick[740891]: [#] ufw route allow in on wg0 out on eth0
Sep 26 03:12:36 racknerd-04bcdf wg-quick[740927]: Rule added
Sep 26 03:12:36 racknerd-04bcdf wg-quick[740927]: Rule added (v6)
Sep 26 03:12:36 racknerd-04bcdf wg-quick[740891]: [#] iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
Sep 26 03:12:36 racknerd-04bcdf wg-quick[740891]: [#] ip6tables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
Sep 26 03:12:36 racknerd-04bcdf systemd[1]: Finished WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0.

Checking Peers from my Desktop Machine (peer)
x@x-desktop:~$ sudo wg
interface: wg0
  public key: x97QeXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXTbL34=
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 33558

peer: YyCfXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX3QCUBvxMTzCw=
  endpoint: 107.X.X.X:51820
  allowed ips: 10.8.88.0/24
  transfer: 0 B received, 8.82 KiB sent

Checking Peers from Server Side:
#wg
interface: wg0
  public key: YyCfXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXMTzCw=
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 51820

peer: x97QXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXT8TbL34=
  allowed ips: 10.8.88.2/32
  persistent keepalive: every 25 seconds

peer: N4liXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXOGUxgYWw=
  allowed ips: 10.8.88.3/32
  persistent keepalive: every 25 seconds

When I ping from Server side:
ping 10.8.88.2
PING 10.8.88.2 (10.8.88.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.8.88.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Destination address required
From 10.8.88.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Destination address required
From 10.8.88.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Destination address required
From 10.8.88.1 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Destination address required

When I ping from Peer side it just hangs in there and doesn't show anything.
Many people say that it is an "AllowedIP" issue, but I tried many ways like
10.8.88.2
10.8.88.2/32 (by specifying the CIDR). None worked.
What could be wrong?

Checking Peers from Server Side: the output shows no connection from the peers is active

Note that IP forwarding and ufw "route" isn't relevant for traffics for 10.8.88.1 -- since they are "input" traffics for the server itself. With that said, it's probably not the problem here since the server doesn't seem to receive the handshake. Is it behind any router / "external" firewall?

I rebooted the server and it seems to be working now
